# What to import for getSpans, getSpanStart, getSpanEnd?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am referring to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#example---adding-a-custom-typeface). I am getting unresolved reference errors for `getSpans`, `getSpanStart`, `getSpanEnd`, and `it`. What package do I have to import? I have already imported these:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.*
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan
import android.text.style.StyleSpan
import android.text.style.URLSpan
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
```

As another question, in general, how do people figure out what to import? Often times, it complains about unresolved reference like this and I find it difficult to find the right packages to import.

========================================================================

full code snippet

```
import android.graphics.Typeface
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.*
import android.text.Spanned
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan
import android.text.style.StyleSpan
import android.text.style.URLSpan
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder

class HtmlLink(val urlSpan: URLSpan, val spanStart: Int, val spanEnd: Int)

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val termsText = getText(R.string.terms)
        val spannableString = SpannableString(termsText)
        val annotations = termsText.getSpans(0, termsText.length, Annotation::class.java)

        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                Snackbar.make(window.decorView.rootView, "URL is clicked", LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint?) {
                ds?.isUnderlineText = false
            }
        }

        annotations?.find { it.value == "terms_link" }?.let {
            spannableString.apply {
                setSpan(
                    clickableSpan,
                    termsText.getSpanStart(it),
                    termsText.getSpanEnd(it),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(this@LoginActivity, R.color.colorAccent)),
                    termsText.getSpanStart(it),
                    termsText.  getSpanEnd(it),
                    0
                )
            }
        }

        textView_terms.apply {
            text = spannableString
            movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `android.text.Spanned` have `getSpanStart` and `getSpanEnd`, which you aready impored as `android.text.*`, are you sure you are typecasting your text as as `SpannedString`

Comment: I am typecasting text as `SpannableString`. I updated the post with the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getSpans`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/SpannableString.html#getSpans(kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int,%20java.lang.Class)) method with a [**`SpannableString`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/SpannableString.html) object.
You are trying to apply it to `termsText` which is a String.

Change `val annotations = termsText.getSpans...` to:

```
    val spannableString = SpannableString(termsText)
    val annotations = spannableString.getSpans(0, termsText.length, Annotation::class.java)
```